# How to use a view (shimmer) as a placeholder for an imageView (Glide)

Tags: android, android-glide, shimmer

I am using Glide to load images to my imageView (which are inside a recyclerview):

```
Glide.with(image.context).load(url)
        .error(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.placeholder))
        .into(image)
```

I see that the Glide library also has a "placeholder" function which gives the ability to load a Drawable to be shown when the image is still being loaded.

On the other hand, for the whole recyclerView, I am using the [Facebook Shimmer](https://github.com/facebook/shimmer-android) library to show that the recyclerview is being loaded.

Looking at my app, everything works fine. However, still there is a gap time between when the Shimmer is dismissed (data is fetched) and the image is shown. This is exactly when Placeholder is needed. I am wondering, is there any way to use the Shimmer as Placeholder for the imageView as well? The Placeholder feature in Glide only supports Drawable and the Shimmer is a View.

Is there any way to convert Shimmer to Drawable? or GIF? Or any other suggestion?

Comment: I've never used Shimmer before, but looking through that repo, there's a [`ShimmerDrawable`](https://github.com/facebook/shimmer-android/blob/master/shimmer/src/main/java/com/facebook/shimmer/ShimmerDrawable.java) that appears to be public. Have you tried playing around with that?

Comment: oh wow! that worked! please post your answer so I mark it as correct answer :D 
Thanks a bunch

Comment: No problem. I didn't really do anything, though. :-) Please feel free to post an answer yourself, explaining any particulars you might have had to address to get it working, if any. Thank you, though. I do appreciate the offer. Glad it worked out for ya. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! :) I posted the answer. Appreciated

Comment: how to add shimer effect using ShapeableImageView ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Thanks to Mike's comment above:
There is a ShimmerDrawable class where you can build a shimmer view as a drawbale which can be used in Glide:

```
private val shimmer = Shimmer.AlphaHighlightBuilder()// The attributes for a ShimmerDrawable is set by this builder
    .setDuration(1800) // how long the shimmering animation takes to do one full sweep
    .setBaseAlpha(0.7f) //the alpha of the underlying children
    .setHighlightAlpha(0.6f) // the shimmer alpha amount
    .setDirection(Shimmer.Direction.LEFT_TO_RIGHT)
    .setAutoStart(true)
    .build()

// This is the placeholder for the imageView
    val shimmerDrawable = ShimmerDrawable().apply {
        setShimmer(shimmer)
    }


Glide.with(image.context).load(url)
        .placeholder(shimmerDrawable)
        .error(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.placeholder))
        .into(image)
```

Comment: What about if I wanted to make the drawable with rounded corners? I can't see any method for that. Should I have to make a custom drawable?

Comment: but can change the color of shadow ?

Comment: It is not working for me. Is there anything I'm missing which is not there in the above answer?

Comment: Not working for me as well. am i missing anything ?

Comment: @AkritKhanna and @K Pradeep did you guys added the facebook shimmer dependency ?

Comment: @oyeraghib Yes, I have added the dependency.

Answer (score 5):

In my case i wanted a drawable with rounded corners as a placeholder which was not supported by the library and i found that you can achieve this using a `ShapeableImageView` from Google Material Designs.

1.Add the Google Material Designs Library into your dependencies
`'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'` with version 1.2.1 and above.

2.In your list item view define your ImageView to be a ShapeableImageView like below:

```
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
   android:id="@+id/shapeImageView"
   android:layout_width="70dp"
   android:layout_height="70dp"
   android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

3.And in RecyclerView.ViewHolder class set the ShapeAppearanceModel of above ShapeableImageView to be `CornerFamily.ROUNDED` with the corner radius you want in pixels and load the ShimmerDrawable as a placeholder in Glide like below:

```
//initialize shimmer
val shimmer = Shimmer.ColorHighlightBuilder()
     .setBaseColor(ContextCompat.getColor(itemView.context, R.color.teal_200))
     .setBaseAlpha(0.7f)
     .setHighlightAlpha(0.7f)
     .setHighlightColor(ContextCompat.getColor(itemView.context, R.color.purple_700))
     .setDuration(1800)
     .setDirection(Shimmer.Direction.LEFT_TO_RIGHT)
     .setAutoStart(true)
     .build()

 //create ShimmerDrawable()
 val shimmerDrawable = ShimmerDrawable()
 shimmerDrawable.setShimmer(shimmer)

 //set the ShapeAppearanceModel to CornerFamily.ROUNDED and the radius in pixels
 val radius: Float = dpToPx(itemView.context, 15).toFloat();
 shapeImageView.setShapeAppearanceModel(shapeImageView.getShapeAppearanceModel()
                .toBuilder()
                .setAllCorners(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, radius)
                .build())

 //load url from Glide and add shimmerDrawable as placeholder
 Glide.with(itemView.context).load(item.url)
        .placeholder(shimmerDrawable)
        .into(shapeImageView)
```

with a helper class to convert the radius from dp to pixels

```
fun dpToPx(context: Context, dp: Int): Int {
  return (dp * context.resources.displayMetrics.density).toInt()
}
```

And the result of above will be:

[image: shimmer_rounded]

Answer (score 1):

I've develop a library to easy add shimmer/skeleton loading effects.
https://github.com/AgnaldoNP/AGSkeletonLoading

There is an explanation on the README.md about how to use it.
You don't need to add a bunch of layouts to emulate the skeleton, it is automatically  calculated. The layout used to show skeleton is the same show the content.

If you use SkeletonImageView on layout file, you'll just call startLoading() and stopLoading() to control the animation.
I hope I have helped you